# Some problems in conditional probability

Tags: probability

A system process like $x_1 \to x_2 \to x_3 \to \ldots \to x_n\, (x_n =0\text{ or }1)$ and there are abservations of the process$y_1, y_2 , y_3 , \ldots y_n$. Assuming that the system has the following relation. $P(x_{n+1}=c_{n+1}|x_1=c_1,x_2=c_2.\ldots)=\begin{cases}1-\lambda \,\,&(c_{n+1}=c_n)\\\lambda\,\,&(c_{n+1}\ne c_n)\end{cases} \tag1$Also, due to the noise, the observation of each $x$ has the relation $P(y_n=d|x_n=d')=\begin{cases}1-\rho &(d=d')\\\rho &(d\ne d')\end{cases} \tag2$ If $P(x_1=1)=p$, what is $P(x_2=1|y_1=1)$ and $P(x_2=1|y_1=1,y_2=1)$.

---

I am trying to solve it, but there is something I am not sure.

For $P(x_2=1|y_1=1)$, I think there is no relation between the event $y_1=1$ and $x_2=1$ (they are independent), so

$P(x_2=1|y_1=1)=P(x_2=1)=P(x_1=1)P(x_2=1|x_1=1)=p(1-\lambda)$. However, I not sure if it is right or not.

In case of $P(x_2=1|y_1=1,y_2=1)$.

$P(x_2=1|y_1=1,y_2=1)\\=\dfrac{P(x_2=1,y_1=1,y_2=1)}{P(y_1=1,y_2=1)}\\=\dfrac{P(y_1=1)P(x_2=1,y_2=1)}{P(y_1=1)P(y_2=1)}\\=\dfrac{P(x_2=1,y_2=1)}{P(y_2=1)}\\=\dfrac{P(x_2=1,y_2=1)}{P(x_2=0\text{ or }1,y_2=1)}\\=\dfrac{P(x_2=1)}{P(x_2=0\text{ or }1)}\\=(1-p)\lambda+p(1-\lambda) $